# Primefaces Ajax response fail randomly

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using p:datatable and on clicking of row (Command link) I am displaying a panel. Most of the time it is working fine but in regression testing some time it is getting hanged but request is going to ManageBean fetching all the data.
But it is not rendering the panel. This error has no specific pattern. I have put log in all possible place even in phaselistner lifecycle everything looks good.
I checked in firebug response is also coming. from server

I am using weblogic 10.3.6,primefaces 3.5 and internet explorer 9.x

Comment: Can you update some code? First you can try adding `process="dataTableID"` attribute in `<p:ajax event=rowSelect>`.

Comment: I did that but no luck... I am wondering what could be the cause.. May be particular Id is not HTML DOM... But if this is the case then it should not available for each request .... Still looking for solution.

Comment: Did you look in JS console for any clues?

Comment: I looked there...I am not getting any javascript errors. ANy thing else I need to look there.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in a  component in the page where the data table lives. This displays Ajax events and alot more. Then compare the log output for when it succeeds against the output for when it fails. This may point to DOM as was suggested or somewhere else.